# Setting title without ViewBag doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, title

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I've got a strange problem.

I want to set title of page with `<title>HomePage</title>`, but when I run application, instead of HomePage, the title of page is localhost:somePort.
Also, when I go to another page, for example HomePage/First, the title is localhost:somePort/First.

It works with `<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>`, but I'd like to know why the first solution doesn't work. Am I missing something there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have `@ViewBag.Title` in your MasterLayout.cshtml which contains the value for the `<title>` tag.

You need to make sure that you set the `Title` property of the `ViewBag` in your controller.

e.g.

```
ViewBag.Title = "HomePage";
```

Then when the page is rendered you will have your desired title.